# Change color of variables in c++ output

Tags: c++, linux

Im making a wordle game and it would make everything much easier if i could code colors into the game, so the output goes from:

```
flame
__&_!
-----
-----
-----
-----
-----
```

where i use symbols, to something more like real wordle with colors:

[image]

Im using emacs on a linux server and i can color the output of strings using

```
\033[1;31m Sample Text \033[0m
```

to change the color of strings but i need a way of changing the variable output color, something along the lines of this:

```
string word = "water";
cout << \033[1;31m word \033[0m << endl;
```

because if i just use the quotes its not going to use the variable it will just print "word"

Comment: `cout << "\033[1;31m" << word << "\033[0m" << endl;`  You probably don't want `endl` as it forces a flush - you probably only need a `'\n'`

Comment: There is no standard font & color specification in C++ standard. You need libraries such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)